# How do you make a subpage of a subpage for a website using only cpanel that hides the .html file extension?

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory, cpanel

I have a website with subpages that have URLs which look something like this:

```
https://www.example.com/hello/world
https://www.example.com/hello/earth
```

In cpanel, my file structure for those pages looks something like this:

```
[folder]
 hello
 └ [folder]
    world.html
    earth.html
 .htaccess
 index.html
```

My .htaccess file has the following rule to account for missing .html file extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

**How do I make `https://www.example.com/hello` load as a working webpage?**
I have tried simply adding hello.html to the folder to no avail -- like so:

```
[folder]
 hello
 └ [folder]
    world.html
    earth.html
 .htaccess
 hello.html
 index.html
```

When I attempt to access `https://www.example.com/hello` in that example, it leads me to my 404 page, but `.../hello/world` and `.../hello/earth` still work. `https://www.example.com/hello.html` does work, but I don't want the .html file extension to be visible to the end user.

I have yet to find a solution to hide the .html file extension in this situation. Help in doing so would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I attempt to access `https://www.example.com/hello` in that example, it leads me to my 404 page

Because you have a directory of the same name and (by default) mod_dir will issue a 301 redirect to fix/append the trailing slash. The 404 then results from the redirected request when your directive attempts to append the `.html` file extension by rewriting the request (now with a trailing slash) from `/hello/` to `/hello/.html` (which naturally results in a 404).

To prevent mod_dir appending a trailing slash to requests for directories you can include the following directive at the top of the file:

```
# Prevent mod_dir appending a trailing to directory requests
DirectorySlash Off

# Disable auto-generated directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes
```

You will need to make sure your browser cache is cleared before testing since the earlier 301 (permanent) redirect (by mod_dir) will have been persistently cached by the browser.

For security, you also need to ensure that auto-generated directory listings are disabled (unless you explicitly want this behaviour), since when `DirectoryIndex Off` is set and you request a directory without a trailing slash, mod_autoindex will still generate a directory listing even if a `Directoryindex` document is present in that directory.

---

#### Alternative solution

Alternatively, you can still allow mod_dir to append the trailing slash (so a request for `/hello` is still redirected to `/hello/` and so `/hello/` is the canonical URL), but allow for an optional trailing slash in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, but exclude this from the capturing subpattern by using a non-greedy regex.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

With a request for `/hello/` then `hello` is captured by the parenthesised subpattern, so it is rewritten to `hello.html` as above.

Comment: Ah, one line of code. Wonderful. Thank you very much for the assistance!

Comment: @TGekko You're welcome. I've added an alternative solution to my answer, that _might_ be preferable in some cases. This requires just a change to the regex used. However, it would mean that requests for `/hello` in the root would need to be `/hello/` (with a trailing slash).

Comment: Oh, that is useful; I'm glad the solution was just that I didn't account for an automatically added forward slash. Thank you for the modified RewriteRule.