# How to hide file path and html extension in url (cpanel jupiter theme)

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm begginer in this and I can't find anything exactly about this so I write this

My directory looks like this:
Domain.com:

- non important stuff
- .htaccess
- index.html (main page)
- pages (folder)
  -- contact (folder in pages)
  --- contact.html (page with contact info in contact folder)

I use filezilla

I use cpanel and jupiter theme. What im trying to achieve is that when I type domain.com/pages/contact/contact.html I dont see this path /pages/contact/contact.html
Instead **I want to get domain.com/contact**

Is it possible? Whatever I write in .htaccess it doesn't work, because I get 404 error

I tried this: [How do you make a subpage of a subpage for a website using only cpanel that hides the .html file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71577349/how-do-you-make-a-subpage-of-a-subpage-for-a-website-using-only-cpanel-that-hide)

But it really didn't work, same result.

Also whenever I change something I have to clear my browser cache for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible!

In your **.htaccess** file add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Make sure to replace the ".html" after `$1` in the bottom line with whatever file extension you are trying to hide. Also, update your link address values (`<a href="page1.html"></a>`) and remove their file extension (so it looks more like this `<a href="page1"></a>`).

This should solve your issue.